# Loop to remove duplicates only works for the first iteration

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following simple loop to remove duplicates from individual columns. It, however, only works for the first iteration `i = 1`. The second iteration `i = 2` gave

> Application_defined or object_defined error.

The code is basically copied from Microsoft's web site. Thus, I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

```
Sub remove_dup()    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 33
        Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i), ActiveSheet.Cells(100, i)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=i, Header:=xlNo
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just use to `Columns:=1,` (instead `Columns:=i`)

Comment: The reason for the issue is that `Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i), ActiveSheet.Cells(100, i))` has only one column. So if `i = 2` the `Columns:=i` tries to remove duplicates in the second column of that range (which does not exist, it only has one column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In columns parameter just use `1` instead of `i` as every iteration is removing duplicates from single column.

```
Sub remove_dup()
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 33
        Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i), ActiveSheet.Cells(100, i)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next i
End Sub
```